# extract log file data and input directly into xhtml body

Tags: python, html, xhtml

I've currently got a python script where a log file is put through and any defined 'excluded' keywords are stripped in the same file. I am attempting to then, after extracting the required words, input this into a pre-built XHTML file directly into the "body" section.

Is there a way that this can be accomplished?

My code for the writing from the extracted log file to the XHTML file is as follows, but this overwrites the XHTML file currently (which I expect as this is where I am stuck).

I have read up on BeautifulSoup but I don't want to go down that path, I want to strictly keep this all executed within the python file (if possible).

```
contents = open('\path\to\file.log','r')
with open("output.html", "w") as writehtml:
    for lines in contents.readlines():
        writehtml.write("<pre>" + lines + "</pre> <br>\n")
```

The formatting I have for my XHTML page within the  section is as follows:

```
                <body>
                <tr>            
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
                        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">
                                    <!-- Body text from file goes here-->
                                    Body Text Replaces Here
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this, with open("output.html", "a") as writehtml:

Comment: @dabingsou thanks, that's got it writing into the xhtml file without overwriting anything, but it is not sitting in the <body></body> tags. Is there a way in python to write them into the body tags?

Comment: Can I have a look at my reply below

Comment: @dabingsou please see my reply. I've updated my original question as well.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
# You can read the template data and spell it in
contents = open('\path\to\file.log','r')
# Suppose that the beginning of your template is stored in this file,\path\template\start.txt
start = '''
<body>
            <tr>            
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">
'''
# start = open('\path\template\start.txt','r')
# Assume that the end of your template is in this file,\path\template\end.txt
end = '''
</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </body>
'''
# end = open('\path\template\end.txt','r')
with open("output.html", "a") as writehtml:
    writehtml.write(start)
    for lines in contents.readlines():
        writehtml.write("<pre>" + lines + "</pre> <br>\n")
    writehtml.write(end)
```

Comment: writehtml.write(start)TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper. I receive this error when running your answer. Can you also explain where in this code it directly puts it into the body tags? I've updated my question to reflect my XHTML code.

Comment: I've revised it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still having the same error as above.

Comment: Template files need to be saved by yourself

Comment: I hardcoded the template data directly. Do you think it's ok

Comment: Fixed. I figured out where it's gone wrong. Thanks for your help.